# tmux 1.8 + mobaxterm mouse-mode clicking refuses to work

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, tmux

Trying to get mouse-mode clicking panes to work in a tmux session on mobaxterm, but mouse-mode wont work. Scrolling works fine.
I have confirmed mouse-mouse is on using `show-options -gw`

This system is ancient btw, Ubuntu14. No I cant upgrade it I don't have control over it.